# Where do Sims come from when they use an airplane?

Tags: simcity-2013

When you create an airport and Sims come to your city, where do they come from? Existing cities from other players, other cities in your game, do they just pop up?

Comment: One would presume they would come from different cities and countries from all over the world? It would be strange if you just build 1 city in the game and that it is the only city in the world...

Comment: it's a game... They can be created by the game, coming from nowhere.

Comment: While I'd like to think they are coming from other players cities (and this is kind of why EA decided the game should be online constantly) without seeing actual proof of this, I don't believe they come from anywhere and just "pop" into existence.

Comment: @Philipp Because money.

Comment: I'm downvoting.  FAQ says: You should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.**  What actual problem will an answer to this question help you solve?

Comment: @SteveV. Presumably, if he's playing solo, and Airports pull sims from other cities in the region, he's not going to get many sims without the region being full. Inversely, if the airport pops sims into existence, it doesn't matter if he's playing solo or not.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - That makes sense.  Removed the vote.

Comment: I would guess they arrive much the same way that people arrive via the super highway. lol, pun.

Comment: @Philipp that was kind of entirely my point. EA issued (afaik) some "reasons" why the game is online all the time, yet none of those significantly needed online access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial when the game starts. They explain that the airport is used to move workers from one city space to another. There is a way in the region view to see the flight paths of airplanes between each city.

I think you must have at least 2 cities in the region, each with an airport to have workers fly between cities.

If you have another player in your region, ask them to make an airport so you can share workers.

Comment: Without other cities or airports there are still planes that show up from the edge of the map and fly over, much like in SimCity 4. They can be seen in town, and in the region view. Also, trains, and ships.

Comment: It is the same with the harbour which doesn't have the tourist pier module.